# Django : How to write Django Group by and where Condition?

Tags: python, mysql, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

I have Django Model with five fields and I mention  two fields in serializer class.I need to perform group by and  where ClosingStock>0  condition. I have tried  with this query but am not getting output.

`StoreClosingStock.objects.filter(CLOSING_STOCK__gte="0").values('ITEM_CODE','CLOSING_STOCK')`

I have implemented the same query in mysql its working fine .I want the same output in Django

[image]

Views.py

```
class StoreClosingViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StoreClosingStockSerializer


    queryset=StoreClosingStock.objects.filter(CLOSING_STOCK__gte=0).values('ITEM_CODE','CLOSING_STOCK')
#The remaining Fields 
#,'BRAND_NAME','STORE_NAME','STORE_CODE','ITEM_NAME')


    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['ITEM_CODE', 'CLOSING_STOCK']
```

Comment: What do you wanna acheive here in groupby is it sum of closing stock ?

Comment: Please have a look screen short . Group  ITEM_CODE and SUM of CLOSING_STOCK   , where CLOSING_STOCK   >0

Comment: Please try this if it works:
from django.db.models.aggregates import Sum

queryset=StoreClosingStock.objects.filter(CLOSING_STOCK__gte=0).values('ITEM_CODE').annotate(CLOSING_STOCK =SUM("CLOSING_STOCK"))

Comment: django.db.utils.DatabaseError am getting this error  .Please check the mysql screen short .I want output like that

Comment: Weird!! I tried on one of my table its working fine. Please once cross check or can you send full snippet of error.

Comment: Just try to run above query using ipython, by import django;django.setup() and importing relevant models.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Nr86Sp1 . Nothing change i am getting same output . Still closing count showing 0 also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223029/discussion-between-boxer-robert-and-kasim-sharif).