# My query in Django shell is working fine but not able to work View file

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have some condition in django modelviewset class:Group by ,Filter and greater than

```
StoreClosingStock.objects.filter(CLOSING_STOCK__gte=1).values('ITEM_CODE').annotate(CLOSING_STOCK =Sum("CLOSING_STOCK"))
```

The above query in shell script working fine .When i move to my view file its not working .

This is my Modelviewset class

```
class StoreClosingViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):


    queryset = StoreClosingStock.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = StoreClosingStockSerializer

    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['ITEM_CODE', 'CLOSING_STOCK']

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset=StoreClosingStock.objects.filter(CLOSING_STOCK__gte=1).values('ITEM_CODE').annotate(CLOSING_STOCK =Sum("CLOSING_STOCK"))

        return  queryset
```

Please check out the Same problem  which i posted [statckoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64351792/django-how-to-write-django-group-by-and-where-condition)

Comment: what error do you get? and how is the first query run in script mode?

Comment: DatabaseError at /ITEMCODE/    .Plase have a look for this conversation   https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223029/discussion-between-boxer-robert-and-kasim-sharif

Comment: what happens if you evaluate the query in the shell? You can do that by using `list(queryset)`.

Comment: Shell i am getting output properly .There is no issue @ruddra

Comment: @BoxerRobert what is your expected o/p ? and are you facing any error?

Comment: @c.grey [Please have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64351792/django-how-to-write-django-group-by-and-where-condition)